# Ranorex only tracks dom elements in IE

Tags: ranorex

I've recently began to work with Ranorex and already got Firefox and Chrome working. Internet Explorer only seems to track dom elements for me. I don't get the usual elements I get in other browsers thus I can't track or run any tests.
I've already tried to reinstall ranorex, restart the computer, trying to deactivate security-features in IE and setting a few different ranorex settings.

I've tried ranorex 6.1 and 6.2.0 and for Internet explorer I am using the most recent version. Windows 7 64 bit.

I would love to hear any suggestions which I could still try to get it to run.

Thank you,
Christopher

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to turn off the Protected mode and the enhanced protected mode?

Comment: Have tried that, didn't work but found the solution. Had to turn off MSAA-filtering in the ranorex settings. After that everything worked fine. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Please add it as an answer